# Java implementation of Long.numberOfTrailingZeros()

Tags: java, algorithm

Link to documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfTrailingZeros%28long%29

Here is the Java implementation source code:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of zero bits following the lowest-order ("rightmost")
 * one-bit in the two's complement binary representation of the specified
 * <tt>long</tt> value.  Returns 64 if the specified value has no
 * one-bits in its two's complement representation, in other words if it is
 * equal to zero.
 *
 * @return the number of zero bits following the lowest-order ("rightmost")
 *     one-bit in the two's complement binary representation of the
 *     specified <tt>long</tt> value, or 64 if the value is equal
 *     to zero.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(long i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-14
int x, y;
if (i == 0) return 64;
int n = 63;
y = (int)i; if (y != 0) { n = n -32; x = y; } else x = (int)(i>>>32);
y = x <<16; if (y != 0) { n = n -16; x = y; }
y = x << 8; if (y != 0) { n = n - 8; x = y; }
y = x << 4; if (y != 0) { n = n - 4; x = y; }
y = x << 2; if (y != 0) { n = n - 2; x = y; }
return n - ((x << 1) >>> 31);
}
```

This algorithm breaks long into two ints and deals with each int. My question is why not use y = x << 32 instead of breaking the long apart?

Here is my version:

```
public static int bit(long i)
{
    if (i == 0) return 64;
    long x = i;
    long y;
    int n = 63;
    y = x << 32; if (y != 0) { n -= 32; x = y; }
    y = x << 16; if (y != 0) { n -= 16; x = y; }
    y = x <<  8; if (y != 0) { n -=  8; x = y; }
    y = x <<  4; if (y != 0) { n -=  4; x = y; }
    y = x <<  2; if (y != 0) { n -=  2; x = y; }
    return (int) (n - ((x << 1) >>> 63));
}
```

I tested both methods and averaged. Implementation time: 595, my version time: 593. Maybe the original implementation is faster on 32-bit systems, because I'm using Windows 7 64-bit. At least Java should use something like my version in their x64 sdk. Any ideas?

Comment: They've written code that works everywhere, and shouldn't suffer particular performance penalties anywhere. If they wanted to ship a different version of the code on different platforms, even just 32 vs 64 bit, then they could make it a native method and optimize it properly.

Comment: This is a **0.33%** performance boost  - assuming the microbenchmarking results are reproduceable (what has to be questioned in general...). I strongly doubt that oracle will honor your effort...

Comment: :) Yeah, I'm writing a chess engine which uses this function a lot.

Comment: @function: if the underlying question is, "how do I optimize this function", then number of trailing zeros is equal to `popcount((x & -x) - 1)`, and SSE4 has a 64 bit popcount instruction (http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/x86-64#gpinstructions)

Comment: @Steve: I suppose a native method here would be slower, as each native call has an overhead.

Comment: @Paŭlo: possibly. Obviously there's a time cost to the programmer getting JNI working at all, but after that it's easily tested, and by moving the JNI call up one loop it may be possible to amortize the native call overhead away to almost nothing. Depends how much of this chess engine the questioner is willing to write in a language other than Java.

Comment: @SteveJessop x86 has also had bitscans since forever, and they're faster than popcount too..

Answer (score 3):

A performance difference of 0.5 percent can be ignored in almost every application. If you work on the one application that needs peek performance for this single method you can implement it yourself.

Comment: +1: Changing the order you test two functions or the values you use can make more difference that this.

Comment: @Peter: I tested 10 each and averaged

Comment: @Function, you need to run the test for at least 5 seconds, trying each function first. I suspect that would be about one million times or more.

Comment: Also, the timing might be different for different inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Java, say Java 8, such functions are intrinsics.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l681